# Spring Integration: BeanDefinitionStoreException 'input' in Sink already defined in Processor

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

The error I am getting is this: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'input' defined in org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink: bean definition with this name already exists - Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor; factoryMethodName=input; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null`

My Sink and Processor Configuration are:

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@Import({TriggerConfig.class, TriggerPropertiesMaxMessagesDefaultOne.class})
public class TimeSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private TriggerProperties triggerProperties;

    @PollableSource
    public String publishTime() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(this.triggerProperties.getDateFormat()).format(new Date());
    }

}
```

Processor binding is as follows:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class ProcessRedcapPartnerDealers {
...

    @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Channels.PROCESSOR_PARTNER_DEALERS)
    public List<DealerModel> processPartnerDealerData(){
...
}
}
```

and the Sink binding is this:

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class SinkDataProcessor {
...

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Channels.PROCESSOR_PARTNER_DEALERS)
    public void processInboundMessage(@Payload List<DealerModel> dealerModels) {

...

}

}
```

from all the online resources that I have seen, it looks the configuration is correct. Not sure what I am doing wrong but I get this complain about 'input' bean being defined in two places. if I go into Porcessor class its extending Sink, and Source but that should not cause this issue? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Processor` interface simply extends `Source` and `Sink`.

```java
public interface Processor extends Source, Sink {

}
```

> but that should not cause this issue?

You can't have two bindings with the same name.

You will need to create your own interface with a different `@Input` name.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that issue now gone, I create a Source with "myInput" and Sink with "myOutput' and have following config in the application.yml:
`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        myOutput:
          destination: myInput
      default-binder: rabbit`
but now it complains: `Unknown binder configuration: rabbit`

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions in comments, and certainly not YAML, code etc; you don't need a `default-binder` property unless you have explicitly defined multiple named binders. If you are still unsure, ask a new question, posting **all** of your yaml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008105/spring-integration-binder-configuration-for-rabbit