# Spring Integration: Binder configuration (for Rabbit)

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to configure as Middleware for a Spring Integration application.

here is application.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ${vcap.application.name:}
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        myOutput:
          destination: myInput
      default-binder: rabbit
```

The error I get is this:

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown binder configuration: rabbit
```

any ideas how to correctly configure rabbit for sprint integration.

The project is divided into multiple modules, I was given this code form a previous dev of the org. so I might not be able to answer all 'why' questions but here it is:

Module 1: The Source Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencies {
    compile project(':mds-dealer-redcap-common')

    // spring dependencies
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud.stream.app/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-time
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-time:2.0.0.RC1'
}
```

Module 2: The Sync gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

dependencies {
    compile project(':mds-dealer-redcap-common')

    // spring dependencies
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit'


    //core common modules
    compile ('common:common-domain:latest.integration')


    // database dependencies
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
//    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.0.RELEASE'


    // others
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.23'

    //Logging dependency
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'

    //test dependencies
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Module 3: The Processor

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
dependencies {
    compile project(':mds-dealer-redcap-common')

    // spring dependencies
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.23'

    //core common modules
    compile ('common:common-domain:latest.integration')

    // database dependencies
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
//    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.10.0.RELEASE'


    //Logging dependency
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'

    //test dependencies
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The main app Gradle snippet:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"dependencies {
    compile project(':mds-dealer-redcap-common'), project(':mds-dealer-redcap-source'), project(':mds-dealer-redcap-processor'), project(':mds-dealer-redcap-sink')

    // spring dependencies
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'  
    compile('common:responseheaders:latest.integration'){ changing=true }

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How is all this being started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 new AggregateApplicationBuilder(DealerRedcapIngestionStarter.class)
                .from(StreamTrigger.class)
                .via(DealerRedcapProcessor.class)
                .to(DealerRedcapSink.class).run(args);
    }
```

For versions of the dependencies I am using this:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Greenwich.SR1'
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:${springBootVersion}"

    }
}
```

And spring boot version is 2.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: Please, stop marking your questions with `spring-integration` tag when the subject is really about `spring-cloud-stream`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream

Comment: sorry tagged it with spring-integration because of middleware, makes sense?

Comment: That's not. When we talk about `spring-integration`, it is really about a Framework: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration, not any general *integration* approach. See tags descriptions before using them.

Comment: sure, Thanks @ArtemBilan I will have a look, appreciate your time for comments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a `default-binder` property unless you have multiple binders on the class path - see [the reference guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#multiple-binders).

However, this error implies that you don't have the rabbit binder on the class path.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the initial build.gradle built by start.spring.io when selecting `Spring Cloud Stream` and `Spring for RabbitMQ`.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR2")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

And these are the resulting dependencies...

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp -> 2.1.6.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.11.2
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.2
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.26
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.8.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.1.7.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:2.1.7.RELEASE
|         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|         |    \--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE
|         |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.22.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.4.3
|         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.26
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.8.RELEASE
|              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream -> 2.1.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.1.3.RELEASE -> 2.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.1.6.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.21
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.17.Final
|    |         +--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final
|    |         +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.4 -> 1.4.0
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.10.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:3.0.3
|    |    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:1.3.0
|    |    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.6.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.6 -> 2.9.9
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.9
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.6.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tuple:1.0.0.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.2.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context:2.0.1.RELEASE -> 2.0.2.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.1.3.RELEASE -> 2.1.6.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-core:2.0.2.RELEASE
|         |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.6.RELEASE -> 3.2.10.RELEASE (*)
|         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit -> 2.1.3.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-core:2.1.3.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.1.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.1.3.RELEASE -> 2.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.1.7.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.5.RELEASE -> 5.1.8.RELEASE
     |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
     |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.8.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7 -> 4.5.9
     |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11
     |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11
     |    \--- com.rabbitmq:http-client:2.1.0.RELEASE
     |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5 -> 2.9.9 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.1.3.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.1.3.RELEASE -> 2.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:5.1.3.RELEASE -> 5.1.6.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6 -> 4.5.9 (*)
```

Comment: Hi Garry, I am using gradle and adding that results in in this: 
Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitServiceAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.rabbit.config.RabbitMessageChannelBinderConfiguratio

Comment: Hi @Gary Russell after some further investigation, I have ended up with this error:

`[ERR] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not register object [org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder$ChildContextHolder@7a0f244f] under bean name 'mds.redcap.sink.DealerRedcapSink-2.spring.cloud.stream.context': there is already object [org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder$ChildContextHolder@3672276e] bound`

Comment: Probably some kind of version mismatch; edit your question to show all the gradle dependencies. It's generally best to use start.spring.io to build your initial build.gradle file with all the right versions for the chosen boot version. I edited my answer with the initial build.gradle for Boot 2.1.6.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russell, I have updated the question. There are multiple modules, one module per Source, Processor and Sink.

Comment: I updated dependencies according to what your answer, I am seeing this error: 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not register object [org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder$ChildContextHolder@1846579f] under bean name 'mds.redcap.sink.DealerRedcapSink-2.spring.cloud.stream.context': there is already object [org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder$ChildContextHolder@6cd166b8] bound`

Comment: and this: `Error while trying to register the aggregate bound interface '&org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor' into namespace 'mds.redcap.sink.DealerRedcapSink-2'`

Comment: Please don't put stuff like that in comments; it's hard to read. Edit the question instead (and comment that you have done so). You also need to show the complete stack trace; the error alone is not very useful.